# What are the requirements for Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: system-requirements

I have a somewhat old pc on my hands and i wanted to install Ubuntu, the installing is not the problem but Ubuntu says (at boot) that i do not have enough ram memory. What are the requirements actually?

Comment: How much RAM does this machine have? I've run Ubuntu on Machines with 512mb of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Desktop Edition

```
700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive   but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

Internet access is helpful, but not required.
```

You can read more from this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

If your systems does not meet these, there is also lighter version Ubuntu "LUbuntu", I hope this helps.